# How do I compute $2ab\cos C$ given $a,b,C$? Isn't an operator missing there?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have an equation. For example the law of cosines, $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos C$

So I calculate it all and I get something like this: 2500 cos 130. I calculate the cos 130, and get -0.643 Now what? I have 2500 and -0.643. Do I multiply them? Or what?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually in math the convention is that when an operator is missing and arguments are just juxtaposed, the implicit operator is multiplication.

Comment: So, $2ab\cos C = 2\cdot a \cdot b \cos(C)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Usually in math the convention is that when an operator is missing and arguments are just juxtaposed, the implicit operator is multiplication - Yuval Filmus  
>   So, $2ab\cos C=2⋅a⋅b⋅\cos(C)$ - Ihf

Answer (score 3):

Well as everyone points out there is a $\text{multiplication}$ operator. In other words $$2ab\cos{C} = 2 \times a \times b \times \cos{C}$$